# Yii form Text Field and CHtml Query: how to get single data by CHtml Query into Text Field

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

Hope you are all doing well.

I need some help from you regarding my question that how can I get single data by CHtml Query into Text Field.

for example I am using

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'im_costprice', CHtml::listData(Purchaseorddt::model()->findAll(" pp_purordnum = '$pp_purordnum' "), 'pp_purchasrate', 'pp_purchasrate'), array('id'=>'purchasrate')); ?>
```

BUT I want to get single data into textfiled so that user can edit/ change the data. Such as:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'im_costprice', CHtml::Data(Purchaseorddt::model()->findByAttributes(" pp_purordnum = '$pp_purordnum' "), 'pp_purchasrate', 'pp_purchasrate'), array('id'=>'purchasrate')); ?>
```

It is showing ERROR. **Fatal error: Call to undefined method CHtml::Data()**...
How Can I solve this. Please help me with some idea.

Helps are highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the value of the Purchaseorddt::model()->findByAttributes part in a separate variable and replace that variable in the place of your CHtml::Data section.

Edit - Something on these lines would work. Do remember though that it is a better approach to do your queries in the controller or the model.

```
<?php $x = Purchaseorddt::model()->findByAttributes( array('pp_purordnum' => $pp_purordnum));
       $y = $x['pp_purchasrate'];
       $model->im_costprice = $y;
       echo $form->textField($model,'im_costprice',array('id'=>'purchasrate'));   ?>
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate little more ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check now,

Comment: Getting ERROR **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** in the line **<?php $x = Purchaseorddt::model()->findByAttributes(" pp_purordnum = '$pp_purordnum' ");**

Comment: try now and make sure you set variable pp_purordnum in the controller action.

Comment: Its not working showing error for **array(pp_purordnum => $pp_purordnum)**... I just change something on that **array("pp_purordnum = '$pp_purordnum'")** then it is showing another Error **Table "pp_purchaseorddt" does not have a column named "0"**

Comment: try now should work for sure - made a silly typo in the previous one, about to crash to sleep - If it still shows an error tell me the exact error you are facing.

Comment: Again ERROR **Illegal string offset 'name'**....in the line **echo $form->textField($model,'im_costprice', $y, array('id'=>'purchasrate'));   ?>**

Comment: try this - if it still doesn't work then it is a problem with your model structure. Refer to the rules for defining model parameters to fix it.

Comment: Rohan Reddy::: Thank you so much. It solved my problem. Now It is working well. Thanks Again.

Comment: awesome, but do remember to do all this querying in the controller or the model as it is a more efficient way. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can put code like that

```
$purchaseorddt = Purchaseorddt::model()->findByAttributes("pp_purordnum = '$pp_purordnum'");
```

and then assign like

```
if(!empty($purchaseorddt)) {
  $model->in_costproce = $purchaseorddt->pp_purchasrate;
}
```

then in view use like

```
  echo $form->textField($model,'im_costprice', array('id'=>'purchasrate'));
```

for more information on cactiveform textField http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#telField-detail

Comment: Getting ERROR **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**... in the line **$purchaseorddt = Purchaseorddt::model()->findByAttributes("pp_purordnum = '$pp_purordnum'");**

Comment: check this $pp_purordnum variable is this exist on controller ?

Comment: just for check echo $pp_purordnum; before findByAttributes statement. check this variable contain value or not.

Comment: I just echo $pp_purordnum; then it is showing data PO1400000227

Comment: @SelimReza sorry but I could not getting why you are getting this error. But as par my logic you assign value in your model.

Comment: I got the solution from @Rohan Reddy... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

just simple call the model in controller like this :

```
$data = Purchaseorddt::model->findByPK($pp_purordnum);
$model->costprice=$data->pp_purordnum;
```

that code will automaticly fill the value in textfield

Comment: Thank you. I got the solution from "Rohan Reddy"

Comment: ok nice selim , are u member of yii framewok forum ? i'm member there too

Comment: could you please give me the link to join there ?

Comment: i mean, i ever see you as member in https://www.facebook.com/groups/yii.indonesia/.is it true? because i'm member too in there.